# How to format and edit an Image property after using .get() in GEE to use as input for Image.expression?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have an Image Collection with which I want to use a mapped expression. In that expression, I want to use part of one of the properties as input in the expression. I know I can use `.get()` to pull out the property. How do I format the new object further so that I can use part of the returned property as a value in the expression? The value of the property I'm interested in will change with the image. The property is called "name", but looks like a timestamp and I want just the hour part of that time.

```
var prop = image.get('name')
print(prop)
// returns
// 2009-06-01 23:00:00
// I want just the hour
// 23  
var temp = ee.Image.expression(
  'tmin - tmax * hr
  'tmin' : image.select('tmin'),
  'tmax' : image.select('tmax'),
  'hr' :  image.get('name')... // what goes here in addition to .get() to obtain "23" or whatever hour is in the timestamp?
```

If I use `.get()`, I have the whole timestamp as a "ComputedObject" and I don't know how to change its type nor pull out just "23".

EDIT: Working with the hint that Daniel supplied, I tried to use `ee.String` functions in this way:

```
var hr = ee.Number(ee.String(image.get('name')).slice(11,13).replace(':',''));
```

In my complete env (not linked since it's full of a lot of stuff), I get this error:

```
Image (Error)
Collection.first: Error in map(ID=20090101):
String: Parameter 'input' is required.
morntem: Layer error: Collection.first: Error in map(ID=20090101):
String: Parameter 'input' is required.
```

In the compact example that is in the following link, the result returned is "null".

https://code.earthengine.google.com/474ebea1841fa4b2d0ad756575c0c5c7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should try to cut down your code so it only focuses on the question you actually have (while still being executable).

The `name` property is an `ee.String`. You can parse it into an `ee.Date` and extract the hour using `ee.Date.get()` method. Like this:

```
// Dummy setup
var name = '2022-03-16 23:00:00'
var image = ee.Image([
  ee.Image(1).rename('tmin'),
  ee.Image(2).rename('tmax'),
]).set('name', name)

// Extract the name property, extract the hour, and use in an image expression
var prop = image.get('name') // Your name is an ee.String
var date = ee.Date.parse('YYYY-MM-dd H:00:00', prop) // Turn it into an ee.Date
var hour = date.get('hour') // Get the hour of the date
print(hour)

var temp = ee.Image().expression(
  'tmin - tmax * hr', {
  'tmin' : image.select('tmin'),
  'tmax' : image.select('tmax'),
  'hr' :  hour
})
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/625c3090569795a477f7ebd6f1ffe55b

Comment: I edited your answer by mistake. I was going to edit my question instead. Sorry. But I did have a follow for you anyway. Can use all the `var` creations inside an `Image.expression`? I thought I'd have to have a dictionary for the expression?

Comment: I updated the answer, showing how to use `hour` within an expression.